# Hexdump read offset with c lseek()

Tags: c, hexdump

I got an image file img.jpg and did the following
`strings img.jpg | hexdump -C`
[which gave me this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjyvm.png)
Now I need to get the camera and date information using a c programm with open, lseek and read ...
My question is, how do I jump to the date 2015:08:05 with lseek?
I tried to use the offset 0x40 but don't really know what's going on ...

Edit: As pointed out in the answers the 2 of 2015 should be in 2015 but this code doesn't output 2 but 0.

```
int rd = lseek(filedesc, 0x49, SEEK_SET);


    if(rd < 0){
        perror("lseek");
        close(filedesc);
        return 1;
    }   

    read(filedesc, &output, 1);

    printf("%d", output);
```

Comment: You could use `fopen` and `fread` to read in the first part of the file to a buffer, and then pick what you want out of the buffer.

Comment: Is `output` memory allocated? How is it defined?

Comment: Also, don't print it as a number with `%d`, it's a `char` - use `%c`

Comment: Output is simply int output;

Comment: You are reading 1 byte into a multi-byte `int`.

Comment: `lseek()` returns `off_t`, not `int`.  While it may "work" on your system or with the values you're using, when you use the wrong type it's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: The offset of `'2'` in `img.jpg` and in `strings img.jpg` is not similar. By opening the file and `lseek` in it you'll get the offset inside the file itself! Run `cat img.jpg | hexdump -C` and then the offset will fit. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out! Solved my problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x40` is the address represents the beginning of the row. The `2` in `2015` is in address `0x49` - that's the address you need. Its content is `32` in Hexa or `2` as text.

In every row, the addresses go like that - for the line begins with `0x40`:

`0x40 0x41 0x42 ... 0x48 0x49 0x4A 0x4B ... 0x4F`. Then begins the next row.

The columns in the file are:

- Left column - the first address in the line.
- Middle column - the content of every address in Hexa.
- Right column - the content of every address in textual representation.

You should check of course that this offset is true for *every* JPG file.

ADDITION: Running `hexdump -C` will give different results when executing on `strings img.jpg` and when executing on `img.jpg`. If you're searching for a specific data in the **file** you should examine `cat img.jpg | hexdump -C`. The offsets *there* will fit the results of `fopen` the file and then `lseek` in it.

Comment: Thank you very much .. but as you can see in my edited question somehow I don't progress with this ...